# Elasticsearch 6.3 - Filtering on nested field count

Tags: elasticsearch, count, nested

I've encountered something that I thought would be simple but is causing me quite the headache.

I have a simple user doc, with comments as a nested field.

I wanted to filter out all the users without comments, I couldn't find a suitable query to do it - using script in the query keeps saying that comments field is not present on the _doc type.

When using exists query on the nested fields it became a lot slower and I'd rather avoid using it for now.

Comment: Which query exactly are you running with `exists`?

Comment: `nested: comments,`
`exists: { field: 'comments' }`
apparently under the hood it builds exists for each field in the comments. it's not eating *that* much time, takes 150ms instead of the 15ms for one of my largest collections

Comment: Using `exists` is the correct way with `nested`. To speed this up you should [denormalize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html) that data - for instance, create a flag of type bool or a `numberOfComments` of type int and query for those with `numberOfComments > 0`. Denormalization is *the* intended way to make ES queries efficient.

Comment: Ye, I wanted to do it with transform but it's apparently not supported at version 6.3, and I don't want to make each component that adds to the document also update the number of comments

Comment: I ended up testing only on one field that is required for this nested field